# Joining a pyarrow table with only a few columns of another table

Tags: pyarrow

I have two pyarrow tables - `table1` and `table2` - and I want to join `table1` with *a small subset of the columns* of `table2` on some arbitrary key field(s). Say that `table2` has a zillion columns but I only want `table1` to be decorated with a handful of `table2`'s columns. Note that the nature of the join *keys* is irrelevant to this question - the question is about the non-key columns.

Q1: first off, I'm assuming that `Table.join` *materializes* results right away, so I'm assuming that joining the two tables and then only using a subset of the result's columns would be a waste in terms of memory and CPU. I might be wrong here and I'd appreciate feedback on this assumption.

This said, if my assumption is correct: Q2: what is the best way to `join` with a "vertical slice" of a table - that is, with only the few columns that I want from `table2`? It sounds like I might need the ability to join a `Table` with a `Scanner` but that's not implemented...

Answer (score 1):

You can call join on `table2.select(['col1', col2', ...])` to select the columns you want. It will return a view of table2, so it should be a quick operation.

Comment: `select`, totally missed that - thank you!